# Proving $\partial (A \cap B) \subset \partial(A) \cup \partial(B)$ using cases

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $A$ and $B$ be two subsets of a topological space $S$. I would like to prove that
$$\partial (A \cap B) \subset \partial(A) \cup \partial(B)$$
where $\partial$ denotes the boundary of that set. I already saw a slick way of proving it on here, but I would like to prove it using cases. Here is my proof.

Let $p \in \partial(A\cap B)$, thus for any open set $U \subset S$ containing $p$ there exists $x, y \in U$ such that $x \in A \cap B$ and $y \not\in A \cap B$. Breaking this down into cases we have:
$$x \in A \text{ and } x \in B$$
and one of the following three possibilities:
$$\begin{align} y \not\in A &\text{ and } y \not\in B \tag{1}\\
y \in A &\text{ and } y \not\in B \tag{2}\\
y \not\in A &\text{ and } y \in B. \tag{3}\end{align}$$

In case (2), any neighborhood $U$ of $p$ contains a point $x \in B$ and another point $y \not\in B$. Hence $p \in \partial(B)$. Case (3) is identical and shows that $p \in \partial(A)$, and case (1) does both at once. Putting this together we have
$$p \in \partial(A) \cup \partial(B).$$

Since $p$ was arbitrary we are done.

Is this correct?

Comment: There seems to be an issue with both the title and your proof. One possible approach to prove that $\partial(A \cap B) \subset \partial A \cup \partial B$, is to assume that $p$ belongs to $\partial(A \cap B)$ and is not an element of $\partial A$, and then demonstrate that this implies $p \in \partial B$.

Comment: @user43208 There was a typo in the title and in my post sorry, the intersection is supposed to be a union. I have corrected it.

Comment: @ZENG Yes that was a typo sorry, I have corrected it now. Is the proof still incorrect?

Comment: Thanks for correcting the typo. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: @CBBAM Your proof is incorrect. You have shown that for a given $p \in \partial (A \cap B)$ and an open set $U$ containing $p$, either $U \cap A$ and $U \cap A^{c}$ are non-empty, or $U \cap B$ and $U \cap B^{c}$ are non-empty, it does not lead to the desired conclusion that $p$ belongs to the boundary of $A$ (or $B$).

Comment: @CBBAM Denoting by $X^c$ the complement of any subset $X$ in your space $S,$ note that $\partial(A\cap B)=\partial(A^c\cup B^c)$ and $\partial A\cup\partial B=\partial(A^c)\cup\partial(B^c).$ You can then either deduce your theorem from [the "dual" one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4383664/386889), or prove it directly similarly.

Comment: @ZENG If $p \in U$, with $U \cap A$ and $U \cap A^c$ both nonempty, then wouldn't this imply $p \in partial(A)$ because any neighborhood of $p$ contains a point both inside and outside of $A$ (one possible definition for a boundary)?

Comment: @CBBAM "In case (2), any neighborhood U
 of p
 contains...": no, not *any* U . A priori, only the U you chose before. I mean: some $U$'s may fall in case (2) and other U's in other cases.

Comment: @AnneBauval I think I understand my mistake now. The neighborhood $U$ I chose was specific to $A \cap B$, and not $A$ or $B$ in general, is that right? It seems my whole approach is thus incorrect and I cannot proceed with cases, I will have to use a technique similar to the post you linked.

Comment: @CBBAM Your argument is analogous to showing that all balls (open sets) are either red or blue, which does not necessarily imply that all balls are red or all balls are blue.

Comment: It was not "specific to $A\cap B$ and not $A$ or $B$ in general", whatever that means. But you have to consider "one by one" every neighborhood $U$ of $p,$ and they do not necessarily fall all in the same case.

Comment: @ZENG I understand now, thank you and Anne Bauval for explaining my mistake.

Comment: If you have figured out an answer to your question from the comments then you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @ronno I figured out my mistake based on the comments and so my approach did not work. I ended up reading a proof elsewhere and I thought it would be dishonest to post it as an answer claiming it is my proof.

Comment: You can post it while properly citing the source

Comment: @ronno That is a good idea. Once I have found the source I will post an answer. Thank you.